# How to display monthname and year in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

If date is `10/16/2015`, column is `datetime` type '2015-10-16 10:09:19.443'

How to display only the month and year as ' Oct-15' in SQL Server?

Comment: Don't do this in SQL, do it in your UI layer. SQL is not great at date formatting and nor should it have to be (in most cases)

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: I know that but I am not using in UI, I need to use somewhere as parameter

Comment: what data type is your column?

Comment: If it is a parameter then a date would be far more appropriate than a string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using `SQL Server 2012` or later, you can use the `Format()` function:

```
Declare @Date DateTime = '10/16/2015'
Select Format(@Date, N'MMM-yy')
```

Result:

```
 Oct-15
```

Edit - in light of @lad2025's comment, if necessary, you may need to also add the `en-US` locale:

```
Declare @Date DateTime = '10/16/2015'
Select Format(@Date, N'MMM-yy', 'en-US')
```

Comment: I will add just in case `en-US` to be sure about locale https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/376711 for example when user has different.

Comment: @lad2025 Ah, that's a very good point - I hadn't considered that.

Comment: it is work truly for other language and date type like Persian. I recommended . Good luck

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to run a quick ad-hock query to see results formatted as MMM-YY, but do not have access to [`FORMAT` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) (i.e. use MS SQL Server 2008 or earlier) you can do this:

```
SELECT replace(right(convert(varchar(9), date_column, 6), 6), ' ', '-')
FROM my_table
```

However, if you are writing an application, and would like to present the date to end-user in this specific format, you should do the formatting in the host language.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty simple (and quick) way to convert from `DATETIME`, although I agree with other comments and answers that a parameter should really be kept in the canonical datetime format, that way any date handling is portable across languages:

```
SELECT RIGHT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), CAST('2015-10-16 10:09:19.443' AS DATETIME), 6), ' ', '-'),6) AS [Mon-YY]
```

Answer (score -2):

Look at DatePart method in SQLServer and extract in postgreSQL.

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: He can use a combination of these methods to extract relevant parts and then combine them as needed.

Comment: What methods? Your answer is more of a comment, and doesn't reference or back up anything you say. PostgreSQL is an object database management system and not relative to the question.

Comment: Question does not state which RDBMS and in my book PostgreSQL and MS SQL Server are both SQL Server. What method? What is this if not a method???: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx

Comment: SQL Server relates to Microsoft SQL Server, you only need to read the tag description to realise this. It actually states "Do not use this tag for other types of DBMS eg (PostgreSQL etc.)...